# Mac. Did not EJECT external HD

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite

I failed to EJECT my External hard drive before removing the USB plug. Now my Mac does not recognise the HD when I plug it in. How can I properly EJECT it?

Comment: A bit late now… see if Disk Utility can see it & hopefully fix it.

Answer (score 0):

#### For now

Plug the drive in, and launch Disk Utility from your `Applications/Utilities` folder, and have it check the disk. Something has gone wrong and your Mac is refusing to mount the drive.

#### For the future

There are two commonly used ways to eject a drive, either by dragging the desktop icon into the trash, or by clicking the little eject symbol next to the drive on the Finder window sidebar. Always do this before unplugging a drive, or else corruption or other strange behavior (like what you have now) can happen.